# Manually install Parse PHP SDK without Composer

Tags: parse-platform, composer-php

I've got a client on a shared hosting environment (which I can't change) and I'm needing to install the Parse PHP SDK, but the host won't allow me to install the Composer package manager. Does anyone else know of a manual install method?

Comment: Do you talk about [this package](https://github.com/parseplatform/parse-php-sdk)? Also, do you have git available? If not, wget/unzip? If not, what possibilities do you have?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about that package. I do have wget/unzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `wget`/`unzip` available, just download [latest release](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/releases/tag/1.1.4) zip (bellow the release, [this file](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/archive/1.1.4.zip)).

Use `unzip` to unpack package and load it with [PSR-4 autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/) (the composer's approach).

Answer (score 0):

Composer isn't meant to be an installer, so you are not expected to run Composer on the production machine. What would happen if during your update process Github would be down? No new website version! And maybe also no old version.

Run Composer somewhere else, and then upload the result to the server, after you verified that everything went well.